# Flutter riverpod, override default async value to my new state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Riverpod and I want to use AsyncNotifier, In this provider is used Async value as a default state, I have created my State and I want to use my state instead of the default one.

How can I use my state instead of the default async value notifier?

```
@riverpod
class ExploreController extends _$ExploreController {
  @override
  Future<UIState<ExploreModel>> build() async {
    final result = await getExploreModel();
    return UIState.success(data: result);
  }
```

Comment: Despite there already being answers, I don't understand this question.  Where is "my state" coming from?  Are you not building "my state" in your build right there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable conversion of a `Stream`/`Future` to `AsyncValue` using the `Raw` typedef.

```dart
Raw<Future<UIState<ExploreModel>>> build() async {
  // ...
}
```

Please note that it is generally discouraged to disable the `AsyncValue` conversion.

---

More about the `Raw` typedef: https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/websockets_sync#disabling-conversion-of-streamsfutures-to-asyncvalue

Comment: I don't think you want a provider that holds a Future instead of using the normal AsyncValue strategies... this defeats a lot of why riverpod exists.